# How to access a template type defined in base class from a derived template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typename

Here is my code:

```cpp
// Here can be more types of base classes and they all define `InsideType`.
struct BaseClass
{
    template <class T>
    struct InsideType
    {
    };
};

// The subclass can inherit from one type of base class. 
template <class Base>
struct SubClass : public Base
{
    // Compile-Error on Visual Studio 2022 C++20:
    //   error C2059: syntax error: '<'
    //   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
    typename Base::InsideType<int> val;
};

int main()
{
    SubClass<BaseClass> var;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to access `InsideType` from the derived template class `SubClass`. But `typename` seems to only work when `InsideType` is not a template type.

The compile errors do not make sense on *Visual Studio 2022* C++20:

```
// error C2059: syntax error: '<'
// error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
typename Base::InsideType<int> val;
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You want to type `Base::template InsideType`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, Thank you so much, I found its details according to your answer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name, *The template disambiguator for dependent names*.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
template <class Base>
struct SubClass : public Base
{
    // Compile-Error on Visual Studio 2022 C++20:
    //   error C2059: syntax error: '<'
    //   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
    typename Base:: template InsideType<int> val;
};
```